# infinite while loop in python when integer compared with range

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop

my while code:

```
i=0
    a = range(100)
    while i < range(100):
        print i
        i += 9
```

this goes into an infinite loop...may i know why?

is it because an integer is compared to the list?
but what happens when i becomes greater than 99?

shouldnt it come out of the while loop?

below code works fine as expected:

```
i=0
        a = range(100)
        a_len = len(a)
        while i < a_len:
            print i
            i += 9
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sadly in Python 2.x, an `int` is always less than a `list` (even if that list is empty).

```
>>> 9 < []
True
```

What you want to be doing is using the 3-argument form of `range` so you have a *start*, a *stop* and a *step*, eg:

```
for i in range(0, 100, 9):
    print i
```

Answer (score 0):

`range(100)` is a list of integers from 1 to 100 over which you are supposed to iterate. So, `len(range(100)` = 100. In python 2.x, a list is always greater than an integer. A very simple way to fix this problem is:

```
i=0
while i < 100: # instead of range(100)
    print i
    i += 9
```